# How to access to a variable inside of a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working with fragments and I've found a problem. When I worked with activities and use a custom adapter, I should call the method like this:

```
adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(Activity.this, eventList);
```

Inside of the CustomListViewAdapter I have some component to modify:

```
tv_event.setText(event.get(Activity.KEY_TITLE));
tv_location.setText(event.get(Activity.KEY_LOCATION));
tv_duration.setText(event.get(Activity.KEY_DURATION));
imageLoader.DisplayImage(event.get(Activity.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
```

Now when I started to work with fragments, I put this variables that I said inside of the fragment class, like this.

```
public class ListEventsFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String KEY_EVENT = "event"; // parent node
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "name";
    public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
    public static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    public static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
```

On the CustomListViewAdapter I should call with Activity.SOME_KEY, but now I don't know how to access a variable inside of the fragment.

I don't know if I explain myself well. Thank you.

Comment: what variable are you trying to get from the fragment?

Comment: The keys of the Fragment:

public static final String KEY_EVENT = "event"; // parent node
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "name";
    public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
    public static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    public static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

Comment: Previous, with Activities, I made Activity.KEY_EVENT to access, but now I don't know how.

Comment: ListEventsFragment.KEY_EVENT ?

Comment: Since they are all public static your have to do is `ListEventsFragment.KEY_EVENT`

Answer (score 3):

Because they are public static variables, you can access them as

```
ListEventsFragment.KEY_EVENT
```

Similarly other too